# how to properly execute if in android?

Tags: android

Can anyone please tell why the `if` statement never gets executed even though I enter `ran` in the edit text field and press <kbd>ok</kbd>? When the user enters `ran` and presses the button <kbd>ok</kbd>, I want another button to become visible which enables him to stop the current activity. Basically I want to know why the `if` is skipped.

```
public class Reciever extends Activity{

    protected static final String TAG = null;
    private Button ok,stp;
    private TextView tv;
    private EditText ev;
private String s1,s2,s3,s4;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        s1="nar";
        setContentView(R.layout.stop);
        tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(s1);

        ev=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ok=(Button) findViewById(R.id.ok_button);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            s2="ran";
            tv.setText(ev.getText().toString());
            s3=ev.getText().toString();
            if(s3==s2)//not going inside this loop
            {
            stp=(Button) findViewById(R.id.stopb);

            stp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            stp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();   
                }
            });

        }

    }
    });
    }
    }
```

Comment: It's not called an `if loop`. It's an `if statement`. It doesn't create a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(s3==s2)//no
```

just replace the above line with below

```
 if(s3.equalsIgnoreCase(s2))//no
```

Comment: it forces activity to terminate saying thread exiting with uncaught exception

Comment: it is coz you are writing a click event inside another click event

Answer (score 1):

Use `.equals` instead of `==` to compare the value of two strings.

```
if (s2.equals(s3))
```

Using `==` tests for reference equality. Two strings can contain the same characters but have different references.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare text with ==, you need to use equals.

```
if(s3.equals(s2))
```